# Mac OS X Notarizing Application - The signature of the binary is invalid

Tags: macos, code-signing, macos-catalina, notarize, ditto

I have .app for Mac OS X . I have successfully signed it with my sign in my keychain. I try to notarize it in .ZIP file and have only errors:

> The signature of the binary is invalid

This error for every binary file in my archive. I read about zip/ditto difference for signing and i pack like:

```
ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent app.app app.zip
```

Problems are same.

spctl -a -vvvvv for .app or for binary files show all ok. What should i do ?

Comment: What is the exact command line (anonymize name+team id) you are using to sign the files?

Comment: You will need to inspect the notarization log.  `xcrun notarytool log <uuid>`